# Plugin.Ble library Device Pairing

Tags: bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

We have a new Ble Device we are using to connect to UWP, Android, and iOS devices.
We have used the "Plugin. BLE" library for our other Ble Devices. https://github.com/xabre/xamarin-bluetooth-le.
This new Device requires Pairing for encryption to be effective. We have used ConnectAsync() methods but it only connects it does not Pair. With Connect we are able to get the services and characteristics but unable to get past encryption as it is not paired. Are there any methods we could use for Pairing a Ble?